# How to speed up lookup Slack Channel Name by Id

Tags: slack, slack-api

Currently, if one needs to lookup Slack Channel Id by Name we need to use
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list method.

The problem with this approach is that this method requires pagination, with a maximum limit of 1000 results per page.

In our team we have 10K+ channels which is not only slow to execute sequentially (dozens of calls), but we also hit `429 ratelimited` error, which additionally increases the time of the lookup.

The lack of this seemingly simple lookup ability is very puzzling, is there any workaround to speed up the lookup?

ps. We can partly mitigate this by introducing caching on our side, but it won't cover the case of newly created channels, which would still require a full lookup cycle, which in our case goes as high as 3 minutes.